# DataGridView row is still dirty after committing changes

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

`DataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty` remains `true` after I commit changes to the database.  I want to set it to `false` so it doesn't trigger `RowValidating` when it loses focus.

I have a `DataGridView` bound to a `BindingList<T>`.  I handle the `CellEndEdit` event and save changes to the database.  After saving those changes I would like `DataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty` to be set to `true`, since all cells in the row are up-to-date; however, it's set to `false`.

This causes problems for me because when the row does lose focus it will trigger `RowValidating`, which I handle and validate all three cells in.  So even though all the cells are valid and none are dirty it will still validate them all.  That's a waste.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
void dataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore cell if it's not dirty
    if (dataGridView.isCurrentCellDirty)
        return;

    // Validate current cell.
}

void dataGridView_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore Row if it's not dirty
    if (!dataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty)  
        return;

    // Validate all cells in the current row.
}

void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Validate all cells in the current row and return if any are invalid.

    // If they are valid, save changes to the database

    // This is when I would expect dataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty to be false.
    // When this row loses focus it will trigger RowValidating and validate all 
    // cells in this row, which we already did above.
}
```

I've read posts that said I could call the form's `Validate()` method, but that will cause `RowValidating` to fire, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Any idea how I can set `DataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty` to `true`?  Or maybe a way to prevent `RowValidating` from unnecessarily validating all the cells?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried calling DataGridView1.EndEdit() after saving the data to the database.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work.  `RowValidating` still fires when the row loses focus.  The tooltip says `EndEdit()` works on the current cell.  If there was something similar, like a EndRowEdit, I might be in luck.  Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: If anybody esle ever comes across this like me. I solved this by calling `datagrid.currentrow.datagrid.endedit()` then `datagrid.endedit` and lastly `bindingSource.endedit()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `Validating` firing twice. Once before the an edit is comitted (as expected), but then again on what I think was the `DataGridView` focus changing.

Didn't have any time to investigate.  Quick fix is `this.ActiveControl = null;` I'm not sure if this has any unintended consequences yet, but it fixes the validation issue by programmatically unfocussing the control.

```cs
private void cntrl_MethodParameters_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    //Init
    var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    int row = e.RowIndex;
    int col = e.ColumnIndex;

    //Validate Edit
    if ((row >= 0) && (col == cntrl_MethodParameters.Columns.IndexOf(cntrl_MethodParameters.Columns[MethodBuilderView.m_paramValueCol])))
    {
        string xPropertyName = (string)cntrl_MethodParameters[MethodBuilderView.m_paramNameCol, row].EditedFormattedValue;
        string xPropertyValue = (string)cntrl_MethodParameters[MethodBuilderView.m_paramValueCol, row].EditedFormattedValue;
        bool Validated = FactoryProperties.Items[xPropertyName].SetState(xPropertyValue);

        //Cancel Invalid Input
        if (!Validated)
        {
            dgv.CancelEdit();
        }
    }
    this.ActiveControl = null;
}
```