# DataGridView Column Sorting Descending order C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I got one little problem about sorting data in `DataGridView` control. Before that, I made `BinaryWriter` form that saves my data.  I'm using this line of code to sort my column in Descending order in `BinaryReader` form.

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns[4], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

I have to sort these numbers in descending order - 12, 10, 7 and 5. This is the 4th column of my `DataGrid`. All fine, but everytime my last saved row of data is not sorted and only stay here.

How can I sort the last row ? Something is missing or is there other solution ? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code for where you save your last row?

Comment: Do you have any data validation firing when the user saves the last row? If not you could commit your changes at that point that then re-order and include the last row.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZdcNeUP6 - That's my BinaryWriter http://pastebin.com/FkhLiSzB - my BinaryReader

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that all data is displayed correctly and in order when you first bind the data from your BinaryReader to the datagridview?

Comment: @Stoyan377 if you want to save your data somewhere from `DataGridView`, why don't you sort it after receiving from `DataGridView` and before saving? i.e. by `Linq`?

Comment: @sr28 Yeah, my data is correct from BinaryWriter, just only the last new data row is not sorted and stay in last position.

Answer (score 2):

This question is already answered at [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4d122994-a428-43aa-8147-e0720846e74e/sorting-a-datagridview-programmatically-and-it-sorts-all-but-the-last-row?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

> This is by design, the "last row" is not belong to the data collection of the DataGridView, it's just an empty row for inputing, I don't think it make sense to sort it with the real data records.

So for sorting, you can get `DataTable`, perform sorting on it and then bind sorted `DataTable` to `DataGridView`

Sample code

```
var src = //get DataTable from your source
var dv = src.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "<your column name> desc";
src = dv.ToTable();

dataGridView.DataSource = src;
```

Comment: Presumably this is only technically true on the basis that the data in the last row hasn't been committed to the database yet? As such, if you commit the data you should then be able to safely say it's part of the data collection and therefore include it as part of the sort.

Comment: @sr28 you're right. If you commit datatable with modified last row - you can damage your data. But this question is about sorting and question author did not say anything about is he able to edit data in DataGridView

Comment: True, the author didn't say as much, presumably because they are unaware that the data hasn't been committed at this point. I would assume they would WANT it committed though as they say they made a form that saves their data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you're adding new data into the last row then it won't be included in the sort as it's not committed data. It's still classed as 'dirty' at this point. You need to commit the data when it's saved and then order after that's been done.

***EDIT***

To achieve what you want you should validate the data in the new data row first and then use the datagrid.currentrow.datagrid.endedit() as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043210/datagridview-row-is-still-dirty-after-committing-changes). This can be done with something like this (taken from linked question incase the question gets removed in the future):

```
void dataGridView_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore Row if it's not dirty
    if (!dataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty)  
        return;

    // Validate all cells in the current row.
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for information! Then, how i can make the last row to be included in the sort ?

Comment: Still no luck, any other ideas ?

Comment: @Stoyan377 - can you show the code you've got to save the new row etc?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZdcNeUP6 Here again, this is my BinaryWriter, where i save the information. The idea is - i have to print information on my next form using BinaryReader and .dat file and have to sort the "tax" column in Descending order - like first - 12, 10, 7 and for the last rows - 5. The problem is that my last row with data can't order, all others are fine. My problem is exactly the same like this one: http://bit.ly/1YrmKcT

Comment: I've looked at that link for your code. There's nothing there showing how you are saving new data coming into the DataGridView. From what it looks like you are clicking a button, getting data and populating the DataGridView with it. Nothing there for updating etc.

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1Jos4lh Ok, here's a screenshot of the design view of my forms. On the left, the form where i input the data, on right - dataGridView where needs to sort by last column. It have to be in Descending order. The information is saved in .dat file. Hope it helps !